# Using theme_get_setting getting empty value

Tags: 7, forms

I am using theme settings in my Drupal 7 theme to provide a theme option as follows.

```
$form['mythemename_settings']['loaderImage'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Loader Icon'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
);

$form['mythemename_settings']['loaderImage']['loader_img'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('Upload Loader Icon Image'),
  '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('loader_img','mythemename'),
  '#description' => t("Upload your desired loader icon."),
);
```

I then use `theme_get_setting('loader_img')` to call the value of the setting, but it returns an empty value. I have also added `settings[loader_img] = "loading.gif"` in my theme.info file, but I am still getting only the empty value.

My intention is to add a Image browse button which can be accessed in the admin end  and can be changed time to time. I have uploaded the image but I couldn't find my image inside my projects. Do I need to set a path for the image to get uploaded?

Where are the values of the settings page get stored in the database? I checked my whole database but I couldn't find the value I saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of image input to `managed_file`. Check updated code below:

```
$form['mythemename_settings']['loaderImage'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Loader Icon'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
);

$form['mythemename_settings']['loaderImage']['loader_img'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Upload Loader Icon Image'),
  '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('loader_img','mythemename'),
  '#description' => t("Upload your desired loader icon."),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://images/',
);
```

Values of theme settings are stored in `variable` table. Check `theme_<THEME_NAME>_settings` under name column & value is stored as serialized array in value column.

## Update 1

To get file object use following sample:

```
$file = theme_get_setting('loader_img','tmhgs');
$file = file_load($file);
```

Comment: Thanks patil.I got the value now but as numeric('563').As you suggested I checked the db the value was there.But I could not find my uploaded file in my local.Is that I need to specify the path? For your reference,I printed the theme_get_setting('logo') it shows me the name and path of the file.This is what exactly what I need.Is that anything I need to fetch from the db with the numeric value '563'which I get.
Again thanks for your help.

Comment: The numeric value is reference to `file_managed` table. You can load that file object using `file_load` function and passing the numeric value to the same. Please check Update #1

Comment: That's works!!!.Your answer was pretty clear and understandable.Thank u so much Patil.Sry I Can't able to upvote as I don't have enough reputations.

Comment: Patil I just added $uri = $file->uri; & $url = file_create_url($uri); in my code I got the output url as (http://localhost/myproject/system/temporary/loading.gif) and when I display it in the browser it shows me the Image.But when I check whether my file exists in my local system I couldn't able to find.Is that I need to pull from the system temporary and store it manually in local by using code.
Many thanks for your help...

Comment: To store image under `sites/default/files`, you need to add array element to file field `'#upload_location' => 'public://image_example_images/',`. Check updated answer.